# minikube --kubernetes-version --> Which version are supported?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I know that you can start `minikube` with a different K8s version with `--kubernetes-version`.

But how can I let minikube list all versions which it supports?

I had a look at the [command reference of start](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/), but could not find a way up to now.

In my case I would like to know which one is the latest `v1.17.X` version which is supported.

On the [github release page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases) I found that v1.17.12 is today the latest version in the `17.x` series. But it would be nice, if I `minikube` or `kubectl` could tell me this.

Comment: All kubernetes versions are supported by minikube and by default it deploys the latest available.

Comment: @guettli Does it solve your issue?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yes this solves the issue. I was not aware of the fact that minikube supports all k8s versions. If you create this comment as answer, I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

@Esteban Garcia is right but I would like to expand on this topic a bit more with the help of [the official documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#selecting-a-kubernetes-version):

> By default, minikube installs the latest stable version of Kubernetes
> that was available at the time of the minikube release. You may select
> a different Kubernetes release by using the `--kubernetes-version`
> flag, for example:
>
> ```
> minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.11.10
> ```
>
> minikube follows [the Kubernetes Version and Version Skew Support
> Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/), so we guarantee support for the latest build for the last
> 3 minor Kubernetes releases. When practical, minikube aims to support
> older releases as well so that users can emulate legacy environments.
>
> For up to date information on supported versions, see
> OldestKubernetesVersion and NewestKubernetesVersion in
> [constants.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/pkg/minikube/constants/constants.go).

Answer (score 3):

The following command may be helpful:

```
minikube config defaults kubernetes-version
```